# Retrofit+RxJava Use Case: Continually loop on API request

Tags: retrofit, rx-java

I want to use Retrofit w/ RxJava to make API requests for items that are a certain distance from a given location.  For illustation, this is how it might it may look for Retrofit w/o RxJava:

```
API api = ...
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
int miles = 50;
do {
  items = api.getItems(lon, lat, distance);
  miles += 50;
 } while (items.size() == 0);
```

Essentially, we'll keep increasing the distance until we get a response that has at least 1 item.

What's the best way to handle this kind of workflow with RxJava?

Answer (score 3):

You can a combination of `range`, `concatMap` and `filter` for this purpose:

```
static Observable<Integer> getItems(int distance) {
    if (distance < 500) {
        return Observable.<Integer>empty().delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
    return Observable.just(1).delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable
    .range(1, 20)
    .map(v -> 50 * v)
    .concatMap(d -> getItems(d).toList())
    .doOnNext(list -> System.out.println("Got a list of " + list.size() + " items"))
    .filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())
    .first()
    .toBlocking()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
    ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out and see how far I get!